# cannot write to a file using write(line)

Tags: python, python-2.7

When I try to write my `line` to the file ( `f.write(line)` )

I am getting this error. **How do I append a line to a file?**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#32>", line 1, in <module>
    populateMatrix()
  File "C:\Python27\1.py", line 19, in populateMatrix
    doPivot(paramMatrix)
  File "C:\Python27\1.py", line 27, in doPivot
    f.write(line)
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

Here's the full code:

```
import glob
import os
from pprint import pprint
import numpy
import pandas
import fnmatch


def populateMatrix():
    matches = []
    paramMatrix = []
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('C:\\Python27'):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.txt1'):
            matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
            print root + '\\' + filename
            with open(root + '\\' + filename) as f:
                for line in f:
                    paramMatrix.append((root + '\\' + filename + '=' + line).split('='))
    doPivot(paramMatrix)


def doPivot(data):
    df=pandas.DataFrame(data, columns=['Fruit', 'Shop', 'Price'])
    #print (df.pivot(index='Shop', columns='Fruit', values='Price'))
    line=df.pivot(index='Shop', columns='Fruit', values='Price')
    f = open('C:\\Python27\\myoutput\\output.txt','r+')
    f.write(line)
```

Comment: DataFrame.pivot returns a DataFrame, how do you want that to be written to file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs on i/o](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects):

> f.write(string) writes the contents of string to the file, returning None.

```
>>> f.write('This is a test\n')
```

> To write something other than a string, it needs to be converted to a string first:

```
>>> value = ('the answer', 42)
>>> s = str(value)
>>> f.write(s)
```

So your `line` needs to be converted to a string before you attempt to write it to the file.

Answer (score 1):

your `df.pivot(index='Shop', columns='Fruit', values='Price')` is not producing a text string but rather a Pandas DataFrame. To convert it to a string you can do something like:

```
line=df.pivot(index='Shop', columns='Fruit', values='Price').to_string()
```

Answer (score 0):

`line` is a `DataFrame` object, not a character buffer object, and so can't be written directly to a file handler. To maintain formatting, etc. (depending on the contents of your df) you could try calling the [`to_json()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) function, then writing the resulting JSON string to your file. Alternatively, you could pickle the dataframe using [`to_pickle()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html), and write that to a file.

Answer (score 0):

To write and read complex objects you can use [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html)